# Find lowest common ancestor in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c#, binary-tree

I've got the following code to find the lowest common ancestor (the lowest node that has both a and b as descendants):

```
public static Node LCA(Node root, Node a, Node b)
{
    if (root == null)
        return null;

    if (root.IData == a.IData || root.IData == b.IData)
        return root;

    if (root.RightChild != null && (root.RightChild.IData == a.IData || root.RightChild.IData == b.IData))
        return root;

    if (root.LeftChild != null && (root.LeftChild.IData == a.IData || root.LeftChild.IData == b.IData))
        return root;

    if (root.IData > a.IData && root.IData > b.IData)
        return LCA(root.LeftChild, a, b);
    else if (root.IData < a.IData && root.IData < b.IData)
        return LCA(root.RightChild, a, b);
    else
        return root;
}
```

The binary search tree is

```
                      20
                     /  \
                    8    22
                  /   \
                 4     12 
                      /  \
                    10    14
```

**Question**

It is failing for the following cases:

> LCA (4, 8) = 20 but should be 8.
>
> LCA (8, 12) = 20 but should be 8
>
> LCA (8, 23) = 20, non-existent number (23) as parameter.

Any thoughts?

Where Node is

```
class Node
{
 public int IData {get; set;}
 public Node RightChild {get; set;}
 public Node LeftChild {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Did you try a "dry run" with no computer, stepping through your code with pencil and paper?

Comment: i tried a bit, if i remove the 2nd, 3rd and 4th condition everything passes but this case fails LCA (12, 14) = 12 but should be 8.

Comment: By your definition, the output is actually correct.

Comment: @st0le - How can LCA of 4 and 8 is 20? the lowest node (depth wise) is 8.

Comment: @parsh, i guess it depends on how strict your definition of `descendant` is...

Comment: @st0le, sorry if I have misunderstood, am referring to wiki's - The lowest common ancestor is defined between two nodes v and w as the lowest node in T that has both v and w as descendants (where we allow a **node to be a descendant of itself)**. so isn't then 8 the correct answer for 8 and 12?

Comment: So any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427656/find-lowest-common-ancestor-bst-when-one-or-both-nodes-doesnt-exist/8428179#8428179 ?

Comment: Not exactly, since the other q, dealt with non-existent nodes, while this, am trying to find out, what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

If the `IData` of `root` is different from both, `a`'s and `b`'s, but one of `root`'s children has the same `IData` as either of the two, you return `root`, but by your definition, you should return the child if both nodes are in the same subtree. Since you also want to check that both nodes actually are in the tree, that check must be performed before any return.

```
public static Node LCA(Node root, Node a, Node b)
{
    if (root == null) return null;
    // what if a == null or b == null ?
    Node small, large, current = root;
    if (a.IData < b.IData)
    {
        small = a;
        large = b;
    }
    else
    {
        small = b;
        large = a;
    }
    if (large.IData < current.IData)
    {
        do
        {
            current = current.LeftChild;
        }while(current != null && large.IData < current.IData);
        if (current == null) return null;
        if (current.IData < small.IData) return LCA(current,small,large);
        // if we get here, current has the same IData as one of the two, the two are
        // in different subtrees, or not both are in the tree
        if (contains(current,small) && contains(current,large)) return current;
        // at least one isn't in the tree, return null
        return null;
    }
    else if (current.IData < small.IData)
    {
        // the symmetric case, too lazy to type it out
    }
    else // Not both in the same subtree
    {
        if (contains(current,small) && contains(current,large)) return current;
    }
    return null; // at least one not in tree
}

public static bool contains(Node root, Node target)
{
    if (root == null) return false;
    if (root.IData == target.IData) return true;
    if (root.IData < target.IData) return contains(root.RightChild,target);
    return contains(root.LeftChild,target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does IData have the equality operator (==) defined?  If not, you are just comparing the references and not the object themselves.

This explains it fairly well:
http://www.ikriv.com/en/prog/info/dotnet/ObjectEquality.html

Comment: IData is of type int, updated the question with the class def.

Answer (score 0):

Here is C# version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LCA
{
    class Node
    {
        public Node(int data, Node a, Node b)
        {
            IData = data;
            LeftChild = a;
            RightChild = b;
        }

        public int IData { get; set; }
        public Node RightChild { get; set; }
        public Node LeftChild { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static Node a = new Node(10, null, null);
        static Node b = new Node(14, null, null);
        static Node ab = new Node(12, a, b);
        static Node c = new Node(4, null, null);
        static Node ac = new Node(8, c, ab);
        static Node d = new Node(22, null, null);
        static Node root = new Node(20, ac, d);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line;
            line = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] ip = line.Split(' ');
            int ip1 = -1;
            int ip2 = -1;

            if (ip.Length == 2)
            {
                Int32.TryParse(ip[0], out ip1);
                Int32.TryParse(ip[1], out ip2);
                int i = -1;
                Node node = null;
                Node node1 = new Node(ip1, null, null);
                Node node2 = new Node(ip2, null, null);
                if (contains(root, node1))
                {
                    if (!contains(root, node2))
                        node = node1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!contains(root, node2))
                        node = new Node(-1, null, null);
                    else
                        node = node2;
                }
                if (node == null)
                    node = LCA(root, node1, node2);

                Int32.TryParse(node.IData.ToString(), out i);

                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static Node LCA(Node root, Node a, Node b)
        {
            if (root == null) return null;

            Node small, large, current = root;
            if (a.IData < b.IData)
            {
                small = a;
                large = b;
            }
            else
            {
                small = b;
                large = a;
            }
            if (large.IData < current.IData)
            {
                do
                {
                    current = current.LeftChild;
                } while (current != null && large.IData < current.IData);
                if (current == null) return null;
                if (current.IData < small.IData) return LCA(current, small, large);
                // if we get here, current has the same IData as one of the two, the two are
                // in different subtrees, or not both are in the tree
                if (contains(current, small) && contains(current, large)) return current;
                // at least one isn't in the tree, return null
                return null;
            }
            else if (current.IData < small.IData)
            {
                do
                {
                    current = current.RightChild;
                } while (current != null && current.IData < small.IData);
                if (current == null) return null;
                if (current.IData < small.IData) return LCA(current, small, large);
                // if we get here, current has the same IData as one of the two, the two are
                // in different subtrees, or not both are in the tree
                if (contains(current, small) && contains(current, large)) return current;
                // at least one isn't in the tree, return null
                return null;
            }
            else // Not both in the same subtree
            {
                if (contains(current, small) && contains(current, large)) return current;
            }
            return null; // at least one not in tree
        }

        public static bool contains(Node root, Node target)
        {
            if (root == null) return false;
            if (root.IData == target.IData) return true;
            if (root.IData < target.IData) return contains(root.RightChild, target);
            return contains(root.LeftChild, target);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Console.WriteLine("\n\n /* Lowest Common Ancestor */");
int v1 = 4, v2 = 8;
Node lca = LCA(Root, v1, v2);
Console.WriteLine("LCA of {0} and {1} is: {2}", v1, v2, (lca != null ? lca.Data.ToString() : "No LCA Found"));


public static Node LCA(Node root, int v1, int v2)
{
        if (root == null)
            return null;

        if (root.Data > v1 && root.Data > v2)
            return LCA(root.Left, v1, v2);
        else if (root.Data < v1 && root.Data < v2)
            return LCA(root.Right, v1, v2);
        else
            return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding c# iterative version for finding common ancestor in Binary Search tree for reference:

```
public BinaryTreeNode BstLeastCommonAncestor(int e1, int e2)
    {
        //ensure both elements are there in the bst
        var n1 = this.BstFind(e1, throwIfNotFound: true);
        if(e1 == e2)
        {
            return n1;
        }
        this.BstFind(e2, throwIfNotFound: true);
        BinaryTreeNode leastCommonAcncestor = this._root;
        var iterativeNode = this._root;
        while(iterativeNode != null)
        {
            if((iterativeNode.Element > e1 ) && (iterativeNode.Element > e2))
            {
                iterativeNode = iterativeNode.Left;
            }
            else if((iterativeNode.Element < e1) && (iterativeNode.Element < e2))
            {
                iterativeNode = iterativeNode.Right;
            }
            else
            {
                //i.e; either iterative node is equal to e1 or e2 or in between e1 and e2
                return iterativeNode;
            }
        }
```

**Where Find is defined as below**

```
public BinaryTreeNode Find(int e, bool throwIfNotFound)
        {
            var iterativenode = this._root;
            while(iterativenode != null)
            {
                if(iterativenode.Element == e)
                {
                    return iterativenode;
                }
                if(e < iterativenode.Element)
                {
                    iterativenode = iterativenode.Left;
                }
                if(e > iterativenode.Element)
                {
                    iterativenode = iterativenode.Right;
                }
            }
            if(throwIfNotFound)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Given element {0} is not found", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**And BinaryTreeNode is defined as:**

```
class BinaryTreeNode
    {
        public int Element;
        public BinaryTreeNode Left;
        public BinaryTreeNode Right;

    }
```

****tests****

```
[TestMethod]
        public void LeastCommonAncestorTests()
        {
            int[] a = { 13, 2, 18, 1, 5, 17, 20, 3, 6, 16, 21, 4, 14, 15, 25, 22, 24 };
            int[] b = { 13, 13, 13, 2, 13, 18, 13, 5, 13, 18, 13, 13, 14, 18, 25, 22};
            BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
            foreach (int e in a)
            {
                bst.Add(e);
                bst.Delete(e);
                bst.Add(e);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                var n = bst.BstLeastCommonAncestor(a[i], a[i + 1]);
                Assert.IsTrue(n.Element == b[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Node LCA(Node root, Node a, Node b)
{

    if (root == null)
        return null;

    if (root.IData > a.IData && root.IData > b.IData)
        return LCA(root.LeftChild, a, b);
    if (root.IData < a.IData && root.IData < b.IData)
        return LCA(root.RightChild, a, b);

    return root;
}
```